# How do I Web Scrape this, using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: html, web-scraping

I am trying to web-scrape an address from a blockchain explorer, how do I web-scrape only the address?
[Html Code that I am trying to web-scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZkdH.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article [ask] about how to ask questions also read this article [mre] about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image. 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question  . Good luck 